# Make running (marquee ) of JLabel in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have develop a desktop app, and I am really new with Java/netbeans. I have done for the display interface, but i want to make some animation of text to display some information of my company in JLabel and i have too long of content, so i want the Jlabel running from right to left to display all of content. Please help

Comment: ["java swing marquee"?](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+swing+marquee&oq=java+swing+marquee&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57.5766j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: [This on stands out](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/marquee-panel/) if you don't mind a ready made solution